# BeautifulSoup4 with Python3 - How to separate and write my ouput data in different files with a rule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

getUrl= 'https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/அலெக்சா இணையம்'
url = getUrl
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
heading = soup.title
refError = soup.findAll ('span', { 'class' : "error mw-ext-cite-error"})
for error in refError:
    err_str = str(error)
    err_str=err_str.replace("<span", heading.text+"~ <span").replace(" - தமிழ் விக்கிப்பீடியா", "")
    print(err_str)
```

This is my output data Which start with  **page name~`<span>`** and ends with **`</span>.`**

For example,(Remember this is a single line)

```
அல்த்தாய் பிரதேசம்~ <span class="error mw-ext-cite-error" dir="ltr"
lang="ta" xml:lang="ta">பிழை காட்டு: Invalid <code>&lt;ref&gt;</code>
tag; name "2010Census" defined multiple times with different
content</span> Before this closing tag </span>
```

There is always a ref-error message at the end of the output data which vary according to the wikipedia page.

1. is not used in prior text.`</span>`

or

2. குறிச்சொல்லுக்கு உரையேதும் வழங்கப்படவில்லை`</span>`

or

3. defined multiple times with different content`</span>`

If i run this code for 1000 getUrl's(page names), i will get 1000 output data. Now i want to group the pages with same error messages in a`.txt` file? Like below,

1. Pages with the ref-error message -->**is not used in prior text**.txt
2. Pages with the ref-error message -->**குறிச்சொல்லுக்கு உரையேதும் வழங்கப்படவில்லை**.txt
3. Pages with the ref-error message -->**defined multiple times with different content`</span>`**.txt

How ?

Comment: The `err_str.replace()` doesn't seem to replace the text, right?

Comment: @Steffi Keran Rani J  While getting the soup, i want to remove,'- தமிழ் விக்கிப்பீடியா'(denotes Tamil Wikipedia) from the article title. So, the code you stated  removes and remains title only. Now, i  thinking that we can use 'ends with function to write, 3 different csv files for the 3 points as above and also 4th csv for rest errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve the problem. Do try the below source code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# Url of the webpage to be scraped
getUrl= 'https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/அலெக்சா இணையம்'
url = getUrl
content = requests.get(url).content

# Patterns to be checked
pattern1 = re.compile(r'not used in prior text')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'குறிச்சொல்லுக்கு உரையேதும் வழங்கப்படவில்லை')
pattern3 = re.compile(r'defined multiple times with different content')

# Respective Error files
error_file1 = open("not_used_in_prior_text.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
error_file2 = open("குறிச்சொல்லுக்கு_உரையேதும்_வழங்கப்படவில்லை.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8")
error_file3 = open("defined_multiple_times_with_different_content.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8")
error_file4 = open("Anomalous_Errors.txt","w", encoding = "utf-8")

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
heading = soup.title
refError = soup.findAll ('span', { 'class' : "error mw-ext-cite-error"})

# Check for error patterns and save it in respective files
for error in refError:
    err_str = str(error)
    err_str=err_str.replace("<span", heading.text+"~ <span").replace(" - தமிழ் விக்கிப்பீடியா", "")
    if pattern1.search(err_str):
        error_file1.write(err_str)
    elif pattern2.search(err_str):
        error_file2.write(err_str)
    elif pattern3.search(err_str):
        error_file3.write(err_str)        
    else:
        error_file4.write(err_str)
    print(err_str)

# Close the files
error_file1.close()
error_file2.close()
error_file3.close()
error_file4.close()
```

**Edited Source Code 2**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import re 

# Url of the webpage to be scraped 
getUrl= 'https://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/அலெக்சா இணையம்' 
url = getUrl 
content = requests.get(url).content 

# Patterns to be checked 
pattern1 = re.compile(r'not used in prior text') 
pattern2 = re.compile(r'குறிச்சொல்லுக்கு உரையேதும் வழங்கப்படவில்லை') 
pattern3 = re.compile(r'defined multiple times with different content') 

# Respective Error files 
error_file1 = open("not_used_in_prior_text.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") 
error_file2 = open("குறிச்சொல்லுக்கு_உரையேதும்_வழங்கப்படவில்லை.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") 
error_file3 = open("defined_multiple_times_with_different_content.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") 
error_file4 = open("Anomalous_Errors.txt","w", encoding = "utf-8") 

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') 

heading = soup.title.text
heading = heading.replace(" - தமிழ் விக்கிப்பீடியா", "")
print(heading) # you can comment this line out
refError = soup.findAll ('span', { 'class' : "error mw-ext-cite-error"}) 

# Check for error patterns and save it in respective files 
for error in refError: 
    err_str = error.text
    print_error = heading+" ~ "+err_str
    if pattern1.search(err_str):
        error_file1.write(print_error) 
    elif pattern2.search(err_str):
        error_file2.write(print_error) 
    elif pattern3.search(err_str):
        error_file3.write(print_error) 
    else: 
        error_file4.write(print_error)
    print(print_error) 

# Close the files 
error_file1.close() 
error_file2.close() 
error_file3.close() 
error_file4.close()
```

Comment: Excellent ! Will you pls refine?
 1)Till .....<code.>&lt;ref&gt;</code.>,  is to be removed.
 2) Then, </span.> is to be removed
 Inbetween the following text needed
 3) Needed text:  குறிச்சொல்; <code>about</code> என்னும் பெயரில் உள்ள ref குறிச்சொல்லுக்கு உரையேதும் வழங்கப்படவில்லை
 4) Needed text:  tag; name "alexa" defined multiple times with different content

Comment: Please do check the new source code under **Edited Source Code 2**